# EDIT / RENAME VIEW - what's best approach - keep it together under edit or separate options?

Tags: design-patterns, filter, edit, flow

Currently, I design edit flow for saved view (filters that allow being saved under "saved view"). The filter bar consists of 4 dropdowns (multiple and single choice), and radio buttons.

The user should also be able to edit the name of the saved view.
Do you know what's the best approach? Keep it as a separate option (edit/rename) or bundle it all together under edit?

Depending on the best solution I would consider an Edit modal window or inline edit feature.

Comment: Sorry, but this is like asking "Should I hang the painting in the hallway or living room?" to a complete stranger who has never seen the house nor the painting. Can you give more context?

Comment: Sure - here is the context. I have a filter bar with 4 dropdowns and radio buttons. Users can save the view and naturally edit it too. On top of that, I need to enable an option for renaming. I wonder what would be best approach: handle renaming as a separate option or it should be a part of editing...

Comment: If it's a separate option (edit/rename), then I could keep it as an inline edit feature. However, if I combine it together (under edit), then add edit fields that are not in the same place - therefore modal might seem more appropriate.

Comment: I changed the description :)